# Mobile version of website: adjust to screen size

Tags: mobile, web, screen, resolution

I realize that creating a mobile version of a site is a complex matter.  However, I've noticed specifically that most large websites when you surf to them in mobile browser ie safari on iphone fill up whole page instantly.  In contrast, my site displays small including font size, has white space at borders, and you need to adjust it by hand to fill up iphone screen.  I gather part of solution is to replace pixel specifications with percentages.  Is there anything else needed to make site instantly fill up pane, perhaps something about html doctype at beginning or other metadata?

Comment: Have you tried using [media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add viewport meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Comment: Awesome.  That did it!  What a difference.